# R prints a value in a row based on a vector

Tags: r

I have a data frame with some words form a couple of interactions and a couple of vectors telling me a value to add in a fourth column. I would like to compare both:

```
WLA
# A tibble: 10 x 3
   word      n  freq
   <chr> <int> <dbl>
 1 okav  2952  2.01
 2 ok    2247  1.53
 3 me    2048  1.39
 4 a     1963  1.33
 5 email 1934  1.32
```

```
E.B
[1] "a"     "ok"    "me"    "as"    "okay"  "email"
```

I would like to achieve:

```
EB
# A tibble: 10 x 3
   word      n  freq status
   <chr> <int> <dbl> <chr>
 1 okav   2952  2.01 OK
 2 ok     2247  1.53 OK
 3 me     2048  1.39 OK
 4 a      1963  1.33 OK
 5 email  1934  1.32 OK
```

I tried the follwing code:

`WLA$status[grep(EB, WAL)] <- "OK"`

However i had no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `%in%` to check whether the 'word' is found in the 'E.B' and assign to 'OK'

```
WLA$status[WLA$word %in% E.B] <- "OK"
```

Here, the first element is not an exact match, so it will be `NA`

---

If it is not an exact match, then `paste` the 'E.B'. with `collapse="|"` and use that as `pattern` in `grepl`

```
WLA$status[grep(paste(E.B, collapse="|"), WLA$word)] <- "OK"
```

-output

```
WLA
#   word    n freq status
#1  okav 2952 2.01     OK
#2    ok 2247 1.53     OK
#3    me 2048 1.39     OK
#4     a 1963 1.33     OK
#5 email 1934 1.32     OK
```

#### data

```
WLA <- structure(list(word = c("okav", "ok", "me", "a", "email"), n = c(2952L, 
2247L, 2048L, 1963L, 1934L), freq = c(2.01, 1.53, 1.39, 1.33, 
1.32)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", 
"5"))

E.B <- c("a", "ok", "me", "as", "okay", "email")
```